# Get child element inside a known parent, with a known *part* of child's ID

Tags: javascript, recursion, substring

Let's say (just for test) I have this code:

```
<div class="p1">
  <div class="fortest">
    <span id="title1"></span>
    <span id="words1"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="p2">
  <span id="title2"></span>
  <span id="words2"></span>
</div>
```

Now let's say I have the "p1" div inside the variable: var node.
All I know is - there is a title inside my node var, which is an element with an id starts with "title".

How can I:
1) Recursivly search for this child inside my current parent.
2) Search only by its ID substr ("title" part).
3) Finish the function when I found it.

Please show me a live example if you can :)
Thank you!

Comment: If you're writing this code now, I'd avoid such a structure as it's a lot of string processing. Use multiple classes instead e.g. <span class="title anotherClass anotherClass"> rather than parsing the ID. Failing that, you'll probably be best served with a regular expression.

Comment: I know it's much better, but it's not under my control, I cannot put any classes or attribute to the DOM. unfortunately I need exactly the solution to the example I need :)

Comment: Since IDs have to be unique, there is no need for any kind of recursive searching.

Comment: Read the question again please. Then you'll understand your mistake (i.e. - I *don't know* the exact id, just that it starts with "title" and inside my parent).

Comment: Have you tried implementing a recursive function yourself? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: I did, but @Tudmotu just showed the perfect solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use querySelector and the [css 'starts-with' attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for this:

```
var p1 = document.querySelector('.p1'),
    titleChild = p1.querySelector('[id^="title"]');
```

Comment: Perfect!! thank you :)
Are there any cross-browsers risk?

Also - where can I learn more about how and when can I use the css selectors? i'll be very glad for a ref. Thanks!

Comment: This is not supported in IE8, but I don't think anyone supports IE8 in modern web applications. If you *really* need IE8, you can use a shim: https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it recursively, if for some reason you didn't want to use `queryselector`.

```
function getChildByPrefix(parent, prefix) {
    var i, child;
    if (parent.id.substr(0, prefix.length) == prefix) {
        return parent;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
        child = getChildByPrefix(parent.children[i], prefix);
        if (child) {
            return child;
        }
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prvfqn59/)